# Does prunsrv.exe use multiple threads to run a Java application as a service?

Tags: java, apache-commons, prunsrv

Configured a `jvm` mode Java Windows service following this tutorial: (https://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/build-windows-service-from-java-application-with-procrun/). I am printing log messages by thread ID to a file in the start and stop methods as follows:

```
 private static boolean stop = false;
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    log.debug(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(Thread.currentThread())));
    if (args.length == 0) {
        log.debug("no args provided, give start/stop as argument");
        return;
    }
    String mode = args[0];
    if ("start".equals(mode)) {
        log.debug("start " + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(Thread.currentThread())));
        startService(args);
    } else if ("stop".equals(mode)) {
        log.debug("stop " + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(Thread.currentThread())));
        stopService(args);
    }
    log.debug("End of main " + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(Thread.currentThread())));
    }
```

This is the log output showing the services starting and stopping:

```
22/Aug/2016 19:22:00,962- App: 441772e
22/Aug/2016 19:22:00,962- App: start 441772e
22/Aug/2016 19:22:00,962- App: startService
22/Aug/2016 19:23:21,259- App: 1ef37254
22/Aug/2016 19:23:21,259- App: stop 1ef37254
22/Aug/2016 19:23:21,259- App: stopService
22/Aug/2016 19:23:21,259- App: End of main 1ef37254
22/Aug/2016 19:23:22,181- App: End of main 441772e
```

The threads IDs appear in the log file which indicates that a new process is started for start service and stop service. Even though the variable `stop` is a `private static boolean` the log file shows that the service are different process (Right?). So, why are multiple Windows processes being created to start and stop my service?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know.... Maybe, `prunsrv` called main function with option `start` in new thread ("thread1" for example), and listened in the next command. When you stop service, `prunsrv` called main function with option `stop` in new thread ("thread2" for example). `prunsrv`, `thread1` and `thread2` have common memory.